# Vue, Vuetify 2, v-data-table - How to show the total raw on the bottom of the table

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using v-data-table (Vuetify 2.x) and would like to do the followings.

1. fasten the total row of the table
2. make the total always visible
3. adjust the total row's  width same as headers

I tried to code the above items, but failed to do so.
For #3, I coded to use `v-slot:footer`, but I can't adjust the total row's .
Here's the code.

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :sort-by="['calories', 'fat']"
      :sort-desc="[false, true]"
      multi-sort
      class="elevation-1"
      :height="300"
    >
      <template v-slot:footer>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-weight:bold">total</td>
          <td style="font-weight:bold">{{ total.calories }}</td>
          <td style="font-weight:bold">{{ total.fat }}</td>
        </tr>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
  new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     vuetify: new Vuetify(),
     data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 200,
            fat: 6.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 200,
            fat: 9.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 300,
            fat: 16.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 300,
            fat: 3.7,
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 16.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 0.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 0.2,
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 400,
            fat: 3.2,
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 500,
            fat: 25.0,
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 500,
            fat: 26.0,
          },
        ],
        total: {
          calories: 3600,
          fat: 105.1,
        },
      }
    },
  })
```

https://codepen.io/UKanamo/pen/GRpyOEP

When I used `<template v-slot:body.append>`, I can't make the total always visible(#2).

How can I code above items?

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself instead of codepen

Comment: Thank you for reply. I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `footer` slot is not part of the actual `<table>`. Use the `body-append` slot to add an extra row:

```
<template v-slot:body.append>
  <tr class="sticky-table-footer">
    <td v-text="'Total'" />
    <td v-text="total.calories" />
    <td v-text="total.fat" />
  </tr>
</template>
```

https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/KKdZrYg

**Note:** A full list of available slots [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/data-tables/intermediate/slots.vue).

To make your footer sticky, add this CSS:

```css
.sticky-table-footer td {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

And don't use inline styling anymore. You can't override it with ease on different responsiveness intervals. Besides, you should strive to keep your code as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am not aware of DRY, so I will keep my codeas DRY as possible.
You use `v-text` instead of `{{}}`, so do you think using `v-text` is better `{{}}`, right?

Comment: To keep code dry means: whenever possible, write code so that if you want to change something, you only have to change it in one place and it magically updates everywhere you used it. If I decide to make total row not bold, I only change 1 line, not 3. As for `{{}}`: it's a minor thing and more of a personal preference. There are rare cases when your app will fail so that an unparsed vue template will be presented to the user. What do you want the user to see? Nothing (which is what a `v-text="foo"` will render) or `{{foo}}` (which is what a mustache syntax will render)?

Comment: Thanks. I have understood DRY as you said. DRY has many merits of writing code. 
My team is using `{{}}`, so I will adjust my team to use `{{}}`.